# Is ink consumption from cleaning after a print job negligble?

Tags: printer, inkjet-printer, ink

I like to reuse paper that's only been printed on on 1 side for small documents that I'll print, read and then discard. Unfortunately my Brother MFCJ430 printer sucks at drawing in multiple sheets of used paper (new paper works fine). To avoid ink smearing and paper jams, I usually load 1 page at a time into the feeder, print 1 page, load another sheet, print another, etc.

It seems that the printer performs a mini cleaning cycle after each print job. Assuming this cleaning consumes some ink: Am I wasting lots of ink by printing 1 page at a time? Or is the ink lost negligible?

Edit:

I found this [blog article](https://blogs.which.co.uk/technology/printers-3/how-much-ink-does-your-printer-waste/) that did tests (50 pages) for various printers. Printing in a batch does indeed consume more ink but the test setup used had long breaks between individual prints, including a variant where the printer would be switched off in between. The results vary considerably though with printer models and electricity costs should also be considered for the overall cost.

Comment: Printer manufacturers claim that used paper produces more paper dust that dirties the rollers and creates feed problems.  OTOH, many printers have duplexers that flip the sheet to print on the second side, so a lot of this may relate to the quality, age, and amount of handling of the paper.  Humidity and how much moisture the paper has absorbed may also affect it, which is why they advise keeping the unused portion of the paper package sealed if you aren't using it quickly.  You can reduce the problem by regularly cleaning the rollers, and fanning the stack of paper when you load it. (cont'd)

Comment: The ink used for cleaning is significant.  You can reduce it somewhat by leaving the printer powered on when not in use if you use it regularly.  Unfortunately, it's needed on inkjets to keep ink from drying and clogging the printhead nozzles.  If your printing tasks are small and infrequent, an inexpensive laser printer may be more economical.  Inkjets contain a tank to hold the spent ink used in the cleaning.  That ink dries to a sludge, which greatly reduces its volume.  But that tank can fill up and need to be replaced, which tells you how much ink is wasted.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I'll clean the rollers and remember to regularly print something for the purpose of maintenance. I have a combined scanner/printer/fax device and mostly use the scanner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I wasting lots of ink by printing 1 page at a time? Or is the ink
> lost negligible?

**tl;dr:** It depends :-). The ink used for printing is probably not negligible - but whether it makes a difference depends on your printer model and your printing habits (and on the price of the ink you buy).

---

There is no general answer, because the ink used by cleaning depends on many factors. Among them:

- Your printer usage. If you use the printer a lot, cleaning will be rarely necessary. If you only use it once a month, you may need to clean before every single print.
- The printer and cartridge model. Some models/cartridges are more prone to drying up, some less.
- The printer firmware. Some printers will automatically run a cleaning cycle, some will leave that up to you. Some may even clean after every power-up.
- Your print quality expectations. Can you tolerate some light smudging and put off cleaning? Do you require perfect prints all the time? May be irrelevant if the printer self-cleans (see above).

That said, here are **some data points from tests**.

- In [this forum post](https://community.usa.canon.com/t5/Professional-Photo-Printers/question-on-amount-of-ink-used-in-Pro-1000-cleaning-cycles/m-p/291284), one user claims that the Canon ImagePrografPro 1000 "fills the ink waste container twice for a set of cartridges". According to [this forum](https://www.getdpi.com/forum/index.php?threads/canon-pro-1000-waste-tank-contains-188-in-ink-thats-25-waste.58920/), the ink waste container holds 150-250g of ink. A complete set of cartridges contains contains 12x80=960 ml of ink. So that would mean a "cleaning loss" of **30-50% for that usage pattern**. Note however that this is a printer for professional usage, so may not be representative.
- [This forum posts](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/4558357) says that a Canon PIXMA PRO-10 used 88ml for about 50 cleaning cyles, or about 1.7ml per cycle. That would be about **2.5% of the cartridge set per cycle**.
- [Here](https://forum.luminous-landscape.com/index.php?topic=103111.0), the cleaning process of an Epson Stylus Pro 9900 is listed as using **between 3 and 176 (!) ml of ink per cycle**.

So yes, the cleaning process may use a considerable amount of ink - a single cycle may consume as much as printing dozens of pages (maybe even more), and in total a significant part of the ink consumption may be due to cleaning.

For details, you'll have to test with a specific printer and usage pattern. Or just buy a laser printer :-).